# How to type an array of different objects

Tags: typescript

I have an array something like this:

```
[
  {
    id: "type_a",
    // A specific data structure for type_a here
  },
  {
    id: "type_b",
    // A specific data structure for type_b here
  },
  // ...etc
]
```

The order of the objects in the array is not defined and they can appear in any order.

How would I create a type in typescript to represent this structure?

So that the contents of the array only contains the defined types

Comment: Define the structures as type aliases (`type X = { id: "type_a", /*...*/};`) or interfaces (`interface X { id: "type_a"; /*...*/ }`) and define the array as an array of the union of those (`(X | Y)[]` or `Array<X | Y>`).

Comment: @T How would I define that each id should only appear once?